# Program doesn't find file (EmguCV)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, opencv, emgucv

I downloaded Example for EmguCV.

I try to change image from default to my image

On default  it was like this

```
 static void Run()
  {
     var image = new Mat("lena.jpg", LoadImageType.Color); //Read the files as an 8-bit Bgr image  
     long detectionTime;
     List<Rectangle> faces = new List<Rectangle>();
     List<Rectangle> eyes = new List<Rectangle>();

     //The cuda cascade classifier doesn't seem to be able to load "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml" file in this release
     //disabling CUDA module for now
     bool tryUseCuda = false;

     DetectFace.Detect(
       image, "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml", "haarcascade_eye.xml", 
       faces, eyes,
       tryUseCuda,
       out detectionTime);

     foreach (Rectangle face in faces)
        CvInvoke.Rectangle(image, face, new Bgr(Color.Green).MCvScalar, 2);
     foreach (Rectangle eye in eyes)
        CvInvoke.Rectangle(image, eye, new Bgr(Color.Aquamarine).MCvScalar, 2);

     //display the image 
     ImageViewer.Show(image, String.Format(
        "Completed face and eye detection using {0} in {1} milliseconds", 
        (tryUseCuda && CudaInvoke.HasCuda) ? "GPU"
        : CvInvoke.UseOpenCL ? "OpenCL" 
        : "CPU",
        detectionTime));
  }
```

}
}

I added change "lena.jpg" to my image - "oleg.jpg".

I added this image to project folder

Via Add Existing File - oleg.jpg.

But when I run my program it says that 'File oleg.jpg do not exist'

Where is problem?

Thank's for help

Comment: use complete path like `f:/myfile/haar/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml` and for other files also

Comment: Thank's it's works)

Answer (score 0):

It works placing your image file on *Bin* carpet.

Regards.